# Acceder a variable this, dentro de otra función, en un forEach, en una clase de Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, scope, this

tengo una duda, estoy trabajando con api maps, teniendo la siguiente clase, como podría acceder al valor de miVariable desde dentro del forEach para modificarlo? Gracias de antemano

```
    class MiClase{

    constructor(){
      this.miVariable = 0
    }
    
    miMetodo(){
     this._poligono.getPaths().forEach(function (path, index) {
    
         google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function () {
             console.log(this.miVariable);   
//Al intentar acceder a miVariable aquí me da undefined, me he percatado que el this en esta pocisión accede al google.maps.event, como puedo acceder al this de la clase principal?     
         });
                      
     });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas podrias simplemente hacer:

```
class MiClase {

    constructor() {
        this.miVariable = 0
    }

    miMetodo() {

        let dis = this;

        this._poligono.getPaths().forEach(function (path, index) {

            google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function () {
                console.log(dis.miVariable);
            });

        });
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que una variable sea compartida entre diferentes funciones, debes declararla como pública previo a la ejecución de la función.

```
class MiClase{

var miVariable = 0

constructor(){
  miVariable = 2
}

miMetodo(){
 this._poligono.getPaths().forEach(function (path, index) {

     google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function () {
         console.log(miVariable);   //Si ya has llamado al constructor, mostrará 2, sino 0.
     });
                  
 });
}
}
```

Comment: En Javascript no existe tal concepto de *público* o *privado* para variables, en todo caso se habla de *ámbito* o alcance *global* o *local*. Las características introducidas en el lenguaje para limitar el alcance de las variables (`let` y `const`) se hicieron pensando en evitar la *polución* ocasionada por el uso de `var` al declarar las variables, y por lo fácil que puede ser cometer errores con la re declaración de variables admitida con el uso de `var`. Lo que propones no es una solución real, sino un atajo peligroso. Saludos

Comment: Estimado, gracias por la aclaración. Obviando la semántica de lo publico o global, el uso de var debería ser depreciado tal como lo informas, salvo en contadas excepciones donde no está asegurada la compatibilidad de let.